# 3D rotation of image does not work as expected

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I am trying to 3D-rotate an image using `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate` but am not getting the expected results:

```
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('./input.jpg')
output_image = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.rotate(image, angle=20, mode='nearest', axes=(1, 2), reshape=False)
cv2.imwrite("./output.png", output_image)
```

Input image:
[image]

Output image obviously broken:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `cv2.warpPerspective` instead, which did the trick